Understanding the Leaves of Equal Height in a Huffman Tree for an Optimal Set-Based Search Algorithm
I'm studying an algorithm that uses a Huffman tree to find the optimal search cost based on probabilities. Here’s how the algorithm works:

Start by checking the most probable element (X1) to see if it's the
answer.
If it’s not, expand the set by adding the next most probable element
(X2) and check again.
Repeat this process until the answer is found.

The set {X1, X2, ..., X8} contains probabilities in decreasing order, and each leaf in the Huffman tree represents the probability of a specific element (Xi) being the answer (e.g., the node labeled 40 means there's a 40% chance that X1 is the correct answer).

I understand how the tree, in general, represents the algorithm. However, I’m confused about the leaves that are at the same height. How are these leaves with equal height supposed to work in the context of the algorithm?

The algorithm you describe doesn't seem to have any use at all for a Huffman tree.  What are you using the tree for?

@MattTimmermans Huffman is exactly the algorithm to use to minimize the number of questions, on average, to arrive at an answer.

I am confused about what you find confusing. You'd need to elaborate on what that is. What is it about equal height leaves that concerns you?

The kinds of questions you ask to traverse the huffman tree are not "checking the most probable element to see if it's the answer", which is what you said your algorithm does.
